# How do I write my own function that will create a bootstrap sample

Tags: r, function, loops

I want to write a function that gives me a bootstrap confidence interval for any vector (x) that will run the loop (n) times. I want to estimate the average body mass index for someone with cardiovascular disease using the sample data I have (cvdonly$cbmi).

This is what I have but it is't working because the CI it is producing is very off from the mean of my sample data set:

```
bs<-function(x,n){
  m_vec<-rep(NaN, n)
  for (i in 1:n){
    cbminorm<-rnorm(x)
    m_vec[i]<-mean(cbminorm)
  }
  ll<-round(quantile(m_vec, 0.025, na.rm = TRUE),2)
  ul<-round(quantile(m_vec, 0.975, na.rm = TRUE),2)
  paste("95% bootstrap inverval for the mean:", ll, "to", ul)
}

bs(cvdonly$cbmi, 100)
```

Comment: you probably want to change the `rnorm(x)` to `sample(x, replace=TRUE)`. It is worth looking at the `boot` package which gives a range of methods for calculating intervals which can behave better

Comment: YES! That was what needed to be fixed thank you!